# Automatic three digit numbers in subsections

Tags: macros

I'm a newbie in LaTeX, please forgive me if this is too stupid.

I have some code like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{qnumber}
\newcommand{\autossection}{\stepcounter{qnumber}\subsection{\theqnumber}}

\begin{document}

\section{A}
\autossection
test
\autossection
test
\autossection
test
\autossection
test

\end{document}
```

Used to automatically print a progressive number as subsection name.

What I want is the subsection number to be formatted like 001, 002, ... 010, 011, ... 100, 101, etc.

Now I only have 1, 2, ... 10, 11, ... 100, 101, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{qnumber}
\newcommand{\autossection}{\refstepcounter{qnumber}\subsection{\theqnumber}}
\renewcommand\theqnumber{%
\ifnum\value{qnumber}<10 0\fi
\ifnum\value{qnumber}<100 0\fi
\arabic{qnumber}}

\begin{document}

\section{A}
\autossection
test
\autossection
test
\autossection
test
\autossection
test

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution using the `numprint` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{numprint}

\renewcommand\thesection{\nplpadding{3}\numprint{\arabic{section}}}

\begin{document}

\section{A First Section}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{A Second Section}
\lipsum[4-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could use the pad - with - zero facility from `siunitx` package and redefine the `\thesubsection` command to print numbers accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}%
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\num[minimum-integer-digits = 3]{\number\value{subsection}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage%
\section{A}
\subsection{One}
\blindtext
\subsection{Two}
\blindtext

%And now jump to subsection 59
\setcounter{subsection}{58}
\subsection{Fifty-Eight}
\blindtext
\setcounter{subsection}{99}
\subsection{Hundred}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: Alternative solution with `\autossection` command (if needed)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}%
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\num[minimum-integer-digits = 3]{\number\value{subsection}}}

\newcommand{\autossection}{\refstepcounter{subsection}\subsection*{\thesubsection}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage%

\section{A -- with autossection command}
\autossection
\blindtext
\autossection
\blindtext
\autossection
\blindtext
\autossection
\blindtext

\section{B -- with direct subsection command}
\subsection{One}
\blindtext
\subsection{Two}
\blindtext

%And now jump to subsection 59
\setcounter{subsection}{58}
\subsection{Fifty-Eight}
\blindtext
\setcounter{subsection}{99}
\subsection{Hundred}
\blindtext



\end{document}
```